# How to resize all subviews/sublayers when superview is resized?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, core-graphics

This question relates to the project: https://github.com/FindForm/FFAngularPointilism

Currently, all the behavior is dictated by the dimensions of the original UIImage. Despite resizing, shrinking, and rotating, the drawing of the "double triangle squares" remains the same. The triangular blur is unchanged regardless of the bounds of the UIImageView to which it is applied.

In my UIImageView subclass, I initialize with a UIImage and call  the following in the designated initializer:

```
- (void)loadMatrix
{
num = 12;

CGFloat width = self.bounds.size.width;
CGFloat height = self.bounds.size.height;
CGFloat theBiggestSideLength = MAX(width, height);

_array = [NSMutableArray array];
_array2 = [NSMutableArray array];

for(int i = 0; i < theBiggestSideLength; i += num)
{
    [self.array addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
    [self.array2 addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
}

for(int i = 0; i < self.array.count; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < self.array.count; j++)
    {
        [self.array[i] addObject:[self getRGBAsFromImage:self.image
                                                     atX:j * 2 * num
                                                    andY:i * 2 * num]];

        int xIndex = ((j * 2 * num) - (num / 2.0));
        int yIndex = ((i * 2 * num) + (num / 2.0));
        xIndex %= (int)width * 2;
        yIndex %= (int)width * 2;
        NSLog(@"%d", xIndex);

        [self.array2[i] addObject:[self getRGBAsFromImage:self.image
                                                      atX:xIndex
                                                     andY:yIndex]];
    }
}

_imageGrayscaleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self convertToGreyscale:self.image]];
_finalbwimage = self.imageGrayscaleView.image;
_imageGrayscaleView.frame = self.bounds;
[self insertSubview:_imageGrayscaleView atIndex:0];

_viewMask = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];

_viewMask.center = CGPointMake(_viewMask.center.x,
                               _viewMask.center.y + _viewMask.frame.size.height / 2.0f);


_shapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
CGRect maskRect = CGRectZero;
CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithRect(maskRect, NULL);
_shapeLayer.path = path;
CGPathRelease(path);
self.imageGrayscaleView.layer.mask = _shapeLayer;
}
```

To draw these tiles, I add a timer and call the following method each interval. Num and row are updating as expected.:

```
- (void)drawTile
{
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(pixel * num, row * num, num, num)];
view.backgroundColor = [self.array[row] objectAtIndex:pixel];
[self addSubview:view];
[self.ksubviews addObject:view];
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(view.frame.origin.x , view.frame.origin.y + (view.frame.size.height))];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(view.frame.origin.x , view.frame.origin.y)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(view.frame.origin.x + view.frame.size.width, view.frame.origin.y + view.frame.size.height)];
[path closePath];
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath;
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
shapeLayer.fillColor = [((UIColor *)[self.array2[row] objectAtIndex:pixel]) CGColor];
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 0;
[self.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
[self.ksublayers addObject:shapeLayer];
}
```

**The following is the correct behavior:**

[image]

When this image is resized via the nib, or its bounds set programmatically, the animatable triangular squares are unchanged.

Comment: I do not understand anything.

Comment: Did you figure out how to handle the uiview size/rotation changes?

Answer (score 0):

You make all the subviews changes on the method Draw Rect inside your class, and every time you make a change, to the superview, you call the method setNeedDisplay.

I didn't understand you question very well, but i hope this helps!